# Does this proof of the well-ordering principle subtly use induction?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

My impression is that the well-ordering principle and induction are equivalent, so you must have to use induction to prove WOP, right? Does this proof use induction somewhere? Or just subtly fail?

> Let $S$ be an arbitrary subset of the natural numbers, and take an arbitrary $k \in S$. Consider the subset $T = \{s \in S \mid s \leq k\}$. Since $T \subset \{1,2,\dotsc,k\}$ it's a finite set, and so it must have some least element $m$. We'll show $m$ is the least element of $S$. Take an arbitrary $s \in S$. If $s\leq k$ then $s \in T$ and so $m\leq s$. Otherwise if $s > k$ then $m \leq k < s$. In either case $m$ is less than your arbitrary element of $S$, so $m$ is the least element of $S$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How do you know a finite set has a least element?  That requires proof, and the usual proof would use induction (or something equivalent) somewhere, since "finite" means "in bijection with a natural number".  Moreover, induction would similarly be needed to prove that any subset of a finite set is finite.

(Alternatively, you could bypass talking about finite sets and just directly prove that for any $k$, every nonempty subset of $\{1,2,\dots,k\}$ has a least element.  But again, you would prove this by induction on $k$!)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah that makes sense. I was taking it for granted, and my undergrad students are going to be annoyed to learn that it's not manifestly true that a finite set has a least element :)